# Evaluate math string in Clojure

Tags: regex, string, math, clojure

I need to implement a function called eval-math-string in Clojure, which takes a math string as input and evaluates it: 
`(eval-math-string "7+8/2") => 11`

So I've managed to break apart an expression using re-seq, and now I want to evaluate it using Incanter. However, I have an expression like ("7" "+" "8" "/" "2"), but Incanter needs an expression like ($= 7 + 8 / 2), where $= is the incanter keyword. How can I feed the list of one-character strings into a list including $= so that it executes properly. If the arguments are strings, the function won't work, but I can't convert +, *, / etc. to numbers, so I'm a little stuck.

Does anyone know how I can do this, or if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: What's wrong with `(str "($=" math-string ")")` where `math-string` is your input?

Comment: Do you have to use Incanter?

Comment: @Piotrek Bzdyl: No, not at all, if you know a better way.

Comment: @jmargolisvt That leaves me with something like "($=7+8/2)" which is a string and doesn't evaluate to a number. $= cannot take strings as input, only numbers and operands, and it cannot be a string itself.

Comment: For solution without Incanter take a look at http://eddmann.com/posts/infix-calculator-in-clojure/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Incanter's `$=` macro [just calls the `infix-to-prefix` function](https://github.com/incanter/incanter/blob/master/modules/incanter-core/src/incanter/core.clj#L2924), so all you need to do is convert your list of strings to a list of symbols and numbers, then call `infix-to-prefix`.

I'm going to assume that the input is just a flat list of strings, each of which represents either an integer (e.g. `"7"`, `"8"`, `"2"`) or a symbol (e.g. `"+"`, `"/"`). If that assumption is correct, you could write a conversion function like this:

```
(defn convert [s]
  (try
    (Long/parseLong s)
    (catch NumberFormatException _
      (symbol s))))
```

Example:

```
(infix-to-prefix (map convert ["7" "+" "8" "/" "2"]))
```

Of course, if you're just writing a macro on top of `$=`, there's no need to call `infix-to-prefix`, as you would just be assembling a list with `$=` as the first item. I'm going to assume that you already have a function called `math-split` that can transform something like `"7+8/2"` into something like `["7" "+" "8" "/" "2"]`, in which case you can do this:

```
(defmacro eval-math-string [s]
  `($= ~@(map convert (math-split s))))
```

Example:

```
(macroexpand-1 '(eval-math-string "7+8/2"))
;=> (incanter.core/$= 7 + 8 / 2)
```